# Фреймворк для кросплатформенной разработки приложений

Tags: android, ios, framework, кроссплатформенность

Какой бы фреймфорк подошел для разработки сразу на IOS и Android? Не игры. Чтобы удобно было работать с веб-сокетами, JSON. Чтобы локализация на другие языки нормально работала.

Плюс еще бы хорошую библиотеку для построения графиков (японских свечей).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если на веб стеке, то можно ionic или react native, для C# есть xamarin, так же на C++ можно